# use C++ range set_intersection() as SQL Join

Tags: c++, stl, set, c++20, set-intersection

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Item1{int id; int data;};
vector<Item1> v1 = {{.id=1,.data=42},{.id=2,.data=69}};
struct Item2{int id; string data;};
vector<Item2> v2 = {{.id=1, .data="banana"},{.id=3,.data="coconut"}};

vector<int> select;

auto ret = ranges::set_intersection(v1,v2,back_inserter(select),{},&Item1::id,&Item2::id);
```

How do I get the result which should be

```
[[{.id=1,.data=42}, {.id=1, .data="banana"}]]
```

?

Comment: according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/set_intersection, result: the beginning of the output range and return : {last1, last2, result_last}, where result_last is the end of the constructed range.

Answer (score 1):

`std::ranges::set_intersection` doesn't do what you want here

> If some element is found m times in `[first1, last1)` and n times in `[first2, last2)`, the first `min(m, n)` elements will be copied from the first range to result.

You need a different algorithm, one that will use the values from both ranges. Adapting the [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/set_intersection#Possible_implementation) of `set_intersection`

```
template< class I1, class I2, class O, class F, class Comp = std::ranges::less, class Proj1 = std::identity, class Proj2 = std::identity >
concept joinable =
    std::input_iterator<I1> &&
    std::input_iterator<I2> &&
    std::weakly_incrementable<O> &&
    std::indirectly_writable<O, std::indirect_result_t<F&, I1, I2>> &&
    std::indirect_strict_weak_order<Comp,
                                    std::projected<I1, Proj1>,
                                    std::projected<I2, Proj2>>;

struct join_fn {
    template< std::input_iterator I1, std::sentinel_for<I1> S1,
              std::input_iterator I2, std::sentinel_for<I2> S2,
              std::weakly_incrementable O, 
              class Comp = std::ranges::less,
              std::copy_constructible F,
              class Proj1 = std::identity, class Proj2 = std::identity >
    requires joinable<I1, I2, O, F, Comp, Proj1, Proj2>
    constexpr std::ranges::binary_transform_result<I1, I2, O>
    operator()( I1 first1, S1 last1, I2 first2, S2 last2, O result, F binary_op, Comp comp, Proj1 proj1 = {}, Proj2 proj2 = {} ) const {
        while (!(first1 == last1 or first2 == last2)) {
            if (std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj1, *first1), std::invoke(proj2, *first2)))
                ++first1;
            else if (std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj2, *first2), std::invoke(proj1, *first1)))
                ++first2;
            else
                *result = std::invoke(binary_op, *first1, *first2), ++result, ++first1, ++first2;
        }
        return {std::ranges::next(std::move(first1), std::move(last1)),
                std::ranges::next(std::move(first2), std::move(last2)),
                std::move(result)};
    }
 
    template< std::ranges::input_range R1, std::ranges::input_range R2,
              std::weakly_incrementable O, 
              class Comp = std::ranges::less,
              std::copy_constructible F, 
              class Proj1 = std::identity, class Proj2 = std::identity >
    requires joinable<std::ranges::iterator_t<R1>, std::ranges::iterator_t<R2>,
             O, F, Comp, Proj1, Proj2>
    constexpr std::ranges::binary_transform_result<std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R1>,
              std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R2>, O>
    operator()( R1&& r1, R2&& r2, O result, F binary_op, Comp comp = {},
                Proj1 proj1 = {}, Proj2 proj2 = {} ) const {
        return (*this)(std::ranges::begin(r1), std::ranges::end(r1),
                       std::ranges::begin(r2), std::ranges::end(r2),
                       std::move(result), std::move(binary_op), std::move(comp),
                       std::move(proj1), std::move(proj2));
    }
} join;
```

And then you'll need to put them into a container that can hold the joined type.

```
struct ItemCombined{ int id; int data1; std::string data2; };

ItemCombined combine(Item1, Item2); // to implement
```

Finally you can

```
std::vector<Item1> v1 = { {.id=1, .data=42 }, {.id=2, .data=69 } };
std::vector<Item2> v2 = { {.id=1, .data="banana"s }, {.id=3, .data="coconut"s } };

std::vector<ItemCombined> select;

join(v1,v2,std::back_inserter(select),{},combine,&Item1::id,&Item2::id);
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40001401395beb35)

Comment: it works, but to me it is not 100% logical, because as part of the intersection, it shouldn't be either Item1 or Item2, but both of them.

Comment: @LudovicAubert oh, you don't want intersection then, you want something similar

Comment: It would be great to be able to do the equivalent of SQL: SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id. Is there in the stl something like set_intersection() to do that ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert that would need e.g. `struct ItemCombined{int id; int data1; std::string data2; };`. Your SQL query would have one result with 4 columns (id duplicated), not 2 results with 2 columns (and a mix of types)

Comment: you could transform both range of items into range of ids, compute the intersection on the ids, and use the ids to access the items afterwards. That's as close as it gets to the equivalent SQL.

Comment: still less handy then SQL though

Comment: @LudovicAubert see edit, I think the name `join` is now more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace ranges;
    
struct Item1{int id; int data;};
vector<Item1> v1 = {{.id=1,.data=42},{.id=2,.data=69}};
struct Item2{int id; string data;};
vector<Item2> v2 = {{.id=1, .data="banana"},{.id=3,.data="coconut"}};
    
vector<int> select;
    
auto ret = ranges::set_intersection(
   v1 | views::transform(&Item1::id),
   v2 | views::transform(&Item2.id),
   back_inserter(select)
);
    
auto rg = select | views::transform([&](int id){return make_tuple(v1[id], v2[id]);});
```

Comment: I would have prefered: auto rg = set_intersection(v1,v1,&Item1::id,&Item2::id); maybe in the future